# Ms Access Query To Get Sum

Tags: ms-access

I have a Ms Access table with four columns; PledgeID, Ref, Paid, and Balance. One PledgeID may have several records. I need a query that will help me get the sum of the Balance for ONLY the last record of each PledgeID. The last PledgeID will be the one with the highest ref. I have attached a photo of the table for easy reference.

[Click To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA7xc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this SQL:

```
SELECT    T2.PledgeID
        , T2.REF
        , T2.Balance
FROM    (
        SELECT      PledgeID
                    , MAX(Ref) AS REF_RETURN
        FROM        MyTable
        GROUP BY    PledgeID
        ) T1 INNER JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.REF_RETURN = T2.REF
```

It would probably be easier to limit the `Ref` field to just numeric - `1`, `2` rather than `PID/2018/00007-1` & `PID/2018/00007-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to find the latest balance per PledgeID and sum these balances:

```
SELECT Sum(Balance)
FROM Balances
WHERE Ref = (SELECT Max(Ref) FROM Balances AS b WHERE PledgeID = Balances.PledgeID);
```

Looking at your sample table, the result seems to be `0.00`.